# 404 error on to many products in cart

Tags: cart, quantity, 404-page, product-view

I have limited the max qty of one of my products to 3. If i try to put 4 of this product in my cart it just shows me a 404 error. I can't find why it does behave like this.

I'm validating the qty option now but this only works for the first time. 
So if the user puts 2 in his cart, comes pack and puts 2 more he gets the 404 error.

Changing the validation in reaction to products in cart directly on the product detail page isn't an option because of the redis cache we use.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: anything in the logs about this error? perhaps turn on developer mode so instead of a 404 error you get the error message stack? this site can help you with that [link](http://www.blog.magepsycho.com/configuring-magento-for-development-debug-mode/)